# how to retrieve data multipe colmns mysql

Tags: mysql

Table name is Test.Contain three columns id,category,units

`Inserted values are:(101,a,10),(102,b,30),(101,a,20).`

How many times `'a'` appear in category where `id=101` and `countsum 'a'`units.

Expected output is`(resultset):totala=2`,`counttotal=30 (2,30)`.

Answer (score 1):

TRY  this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows, SUM(units) AS counttotal
FROM Test
WHERE id= '101';
```

Comment: Thank you .it works :SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows, SUM(units) AS counttotal
FROM Test
WHERE id= '101' and WHERE units= 'a';

Comment: @vvkkumr double WHERE ??

Comment: sorry it spells mistake.SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows, SUM(units) AS counttotal FROM Test WHERE id= '101' and units= 'a';

Comment: just a suggestion dont always use (*) just select the specific field. just like in my answer.

Comment: @Edrich both are same thing, for more info see blog link https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SELECT COUNT(category) as totala, SUM(units) as counttotal FROM Test WHERE category='a' GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, COUNT(category), SUM(units) FROM Test GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You need a `having id=101`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

SELECT COUNT(id) AS totala,SUM(units) AS counttotal FROM Test WHERE category='a' GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT( category ) , SUM( units ) 
FROM  `test` 
WHERE id =  '101'
GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(id) AS total_count, SUM(units) AS total_units
FROM
   Test
WHERE
   id= '101' AND units = 'a';
```